# My LEFT JOIN is not returning correct results. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

When I run my query as `INNER JOIN` between two tables, I get the correct result - 182 in all.

However, when I run the query as `LEFT JOIN`, I get only 8 records back. Am I performing the join incorrectly?

First the code:

```
select e.username,
       e.password,
       coalesce(r.access_level, 0) as orgid 
  from employees e 
       left join retired r 
           on e.employeeid = r.employeeid 
 where access_level=3
```

The `Retired` table has only 182 records. Both tables are related by `EmployeeId`.

The 82 records in `Retired` table also exist in `Employees` but `Employees` table has over 7 thousand records.

One of the fieldnames  `Retired` is called `Access_Level` with a value of 3.

Any ideas why `LEFT JOIN` isn't giving me an accurate result?

Comment: How many records in RETIRED have ACCESS_LEVEL = 3? How many with ACCESS_LEVEL is null?

Comment: Maybe you want to have the access_level=3 as part of the criteria on the join such as `on e.employeeid=r.employeeid and access_level=3`

Comment: @DavidW, ALL the records (82 of them) in RETIRED have same access_level of 3. Reason is that there are certain access priviledges they have the rest of employees don't have and that's the criterium for ensuring no other employee access those other sites. No null values for Access_Level.

Comment: Something isn't consistent, Chidi - your question says RETIRED has 182 records, but in this last reply you state that it has only 82, but your explicit inner join returns 182 records. I'm not sure which is correct at this point. Does your RETIRED table have more than one record for some EMPLOYEE_ID values, perchance? If you could clarify, it would help greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with outer joins and conditions is to move the condition from the where clause into the join condtions clause:

```
select
    e.username,
    e.password,
    coalesce(r.access_level, 0) as orgid 
from employees e 
left join retired r 
    on e.employeeid = r.employeeid 
    and access_level=3
```

The reason you must do this is that the where clause is a *filter* on the rowset,which executes *after* the joins are made. By having a condition on the outer joined table in the where clause you effectively make the outer join into an *inner* join, because missed outer joins have `null` values in the columns of the joined table, but a condition in the where clause will insist there *is* a value there.

Conditions in the join clause are executed *as the join is made*, so by moving the condition  out of the where clause, you allow the join to miss *while still imposing the condition*, but return an all-null joined row if no suitable row is found in the joined table.

---

After some more info from comments, it seems this is what you wanted:

```
select distinct
    e.username,
    e.password,
    coalesce(r.access_level, 0) as orgid 
from employees e 
join retired r 
    on e.employeeid = r.employeeid 
    and access_level=3
```

Comment: @Bohemain,

Your query returned all 7 thousand records. I think it is correct.

Only employees in RETIRED table have access_level = 3. Infact access_level field doesn't even exist in employees table. I am expect a result closer to 82 records

Comment: Maybe you want an inner join then: try removing the keyword `left` from the query and adding `distinct` after the keyword `select`

Answer (score 3):

If `Access_Level` is a column in the `Retired` table then its value will be `NULL` for any rows in Employee that don't have a corresponding row in Retired. Those rows will then be filtered out by your WHERE clause as they *don't* have a `Access_Level` of 3. Moving that condition to the `ON` clause should be enough:

```
select e.username,
       e.password,
       coalesce(r.access_level, 0) as orgid 
  from employees e 
       left join retired r 
           on e.employeeid = r.employeeid and access_level=3
```

Comment: are saying then that your query should return ALL records from Employees table regardless of whether access_level is 3 or not?

Your query is returning all 7 thousand records.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Yes, that's precisely what a LEFT OUTER JOIN does. If that's not what you want then you don't want a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Perhaps you need to be clearer about what exactly the problem you're trying to solve is in the question.

Comment: REmember, @ChidiOkeh, a LEFT OUTER JOIN returns ALL records from the "left hand" table, and provides "nulls" for all columns of the "right hand" table when there is no match across the join condition. The inner join returns only matches for *both* tables across the join condition.

Answer (score 2):

Using a field from the retired table in your WHERE clause is basically automatically performing an INNER JOIN, because only records that have a valid access_level value (i.e., NOT NULL) are being returned.

If you want to see all records from employee, you would need to modify your WHERE clause to account for employee records that do not have a match in retired, such as saying `WHERE r.access_level = 3 OR r.employeeid IS NULL`.